# Value of algebraic functions at algebraic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have read that the value of an algebraic function at an algebraic number (root of a polynomial with integer coefficients) is also an algebraic number, and that all polynomials are algebraic functions. However, if I take the polynomial e*x, its value at algebraic numbers is not another algebraic number.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missunderstanding?

Thank you.

Comment: $e$ as in Euler constant? $f(x)=ex$ is not an algebraic function. The statement "all polynomials are algebraic" is wrong. Polynomials with rational coefficients are algebraic.

Comment: @freakish Yes, it is. What do you think an algebraic function is?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Algebraic functions as [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function). How is $ex$ algebraic?

Comment: @freakish And it is written there that “any polynomial function $y=p(x)$ is an algebraic function, since it is simply the solution $y$ to the equation $y-p(x)=0$”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This is incorrect. The definition of an algebraic function requires polynomials to be of integer (or rational) coefficients: "where the coefficients $a_i(x)$ are polynomial functions of $x$, with integer coefficients.". The example is missing the assumption.

Comment: @freakish Really? Please tell me where can I find *that* definition of algebraic function.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Dude, I've just quoted wiki. How about you read the article, hmm? But I'm happy to hear your definition.

Comment: @freakish As I told you already, that article claims that **every** polynomial function in one variable is an algebraic function. Therefore, it cannot possible support your claim.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos And I'm telling you that claim is wrong. The definition is at the top of the article. It's not the first time for wiki to be wrong. But it's hard to be wrong in a definition. So unless you have another one we are done.

Comment: @freakish The first two sentences read “In mathematics, an **algebraic function** is a function that can be defined as the root of a polynomial equation. Quite often algebraic functions are algebraic expressions using a finite number of terms, involving only the algebraic operations addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and raising to a fractional power.” *Where* is the reference to integer or rational coefficients?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Obviously you didn't read the article. "In more precise terms, an algebraic function of degree n in one variable x is a function (...) with integer coefficient". It's a third paragraph. For the last time: **read the article** or we have nothing to talk about. I'm done quoting the same thing over and over.

Comment: @freakish: wiki has unnecessarily restricted the definition to include integer coefficients. The analytical nature and behavior of algebraic functions (like their derivatives or techniques for integrating them) are not dependent on the nature of coefficients. It would be very strange to think of polynomials like $\pi x$ as transcendental functions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it wouldn't be strange at all. It's a perfect analogy to $\pi$ being a transcendental number. But if there is some other definition then please show me where it is. Also mapping algebraic numbers to algebraic numbers **clearly** depends on coefficients.

Comment: Let me extend on my comment: algebraic functions can be defined over any field extension $K\subseteq L$. And indeed all polynomials in $K[X]$ are algebraic. But not all polynomials in $L[X]$. So perhaps I incorrectly assumed that op is talking about $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. But still unless the extension is algebraic then not every polynomial is algebraic just like not every element is algebraic.

Comment: @freakish: the point of defining algebraic functions is not to guarantee that they map algebraic numbers to algebraic numbers, but rather to show that function values can be obtained from the argument using algebraic operations. I really don't understand why wiki people chose to have that guarantee.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh again: show me a book or article that doesn't use this definition. Otherwise further conversation is pointless.

Comment: @freakish: if one wants to argue via authority (insistence on source) then it is really pointless.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh oh, wow, your "this is not the correct definition even though noone uses different" surely is a better way to argue. Yes, this is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this is the definition of an algebraic function (following [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function)):

> **Definition:** A function $f(x)$ is algebraic if it is continuous in its domain and
>   $$a_n(x)f(x)^n+\cdots +a_1(x)f(x)+a_0(x)=0$$
>   where each $a_i(x)$ is a polynomial with **integer** coefficients.

(Although I don't think that the continuity assumption matters much). The "integer coefficients" assumption is  crutial. It is an analogy to the usual algebraic number definition. Now
the statement

> If $f(x)$ is an algebraic function and $a$ an algebraic number then $f(a)$ is algebraic number as well.

is true in this setup. It is not true if we omit "integer coefficients" assumption. And the statement

> All polynomials are algebraic

is false as your $f(x)=ex$ example shows. The statement should say

> All rational polynomials are algebraic

This one is quite easy to prove. Also I think that

> All polynomials with algebraic coefficients are algebraic

is true but I couldn't figure out the details. And in fact I think that for polynomials this is "if and only if" meaning if a polynomial is algebraic then its coefficients are algebraic.